# How to isolate docker container from the host network (docker-compose)

Tags: docker-compose, containers, docker-network

I have a container that running a simple socket python script that listen on his ip address. I made a network for that container with the `bridge` as the driver. But when I am running the container I can access it from outside of his network using the localhost:port address. I want to isolate the container from anyone that is outside of his network. Can someone help me with that?.

**This is my docker-compose file:***

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  relayG1_1:
    container_name: relayG1_1
    image: image
    command: python3 server.py 10.1.0.5
    ports:
      - 4000:4000/tcp
    networks:
      first_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.0.5

networks:
  first_network:
    name: first_network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.1.0.0/24
         gateway: 10.1.0.1
```

Comment: Your `ports: - 4000:4000/tcp` is telling docker: Please link 4000 on this container to 4000 on the host machine. Just remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to expose port on network, without being accessible from localhost you should use property `expose` instead of ports.

An example :

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  relayG1_1:
    container_name: relayG1_1
    image: image
    command: python3 server.py 10.1.0.5
    expose:
      - "4000"
    networks:
      first_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.0.5

networks:
  first_network:
    name: first_network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.1.0.0/24
         gateway: 10.1.0.1
```